# Deploy only one template from the helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Is there a way to deploy one template from the helm chart? `helm upgrade --install` has to be applied to the chart, but I want to deploy only one file, lets say configmap.yaml. When I run `kubectl apply -f configmap.yaml`, I get an error: `error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 5: did not find expected node content` because there are variables fetched from _helpers.tpl: `{{ include "templatename.fullname" . }}`. Using helm 3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found I can do it this way:

In config.yaml:

```
...
labels:
  my-label: abc
```

Then use the `-l` filter option of `kubectl` to choose only those objects that have this label.

```
helm template name charts/chartname/charts/name --values values.yaml | kubectl apply -f - -l my-label=abc
```

Comment: This is pretty terse. Can you flesh out your answer a bit to explain what's happening?

Comment: For example, I want to deploy a file config.yaml from a chart with a name 'app'. Add a label to the config.yaml if there are no labels by which the file can be chosen: label.for.config="true". Then you render yaml using the command <helm template app path/to/app/chart> and use its output as an input to the kubectl apply command, which will be applied only to the files with a particular label <kubectl apply -f - -l label.for.config="true">

Answer (score 10):

you could try this command:

```
helm template -s templates/configmap.yaml . | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, but I might be doing something wrong.
In the directory where the chart can be found I do instead:
helm template name -s templates/confimap.yaml and it works.
With your command I get "could not find template templates/configmap.yaml in chart.

Comment: @Lethargos The file referenced is specific to the helm chart used, different helm charts will use different conventions.

If you read this it includes a trick to see all the files that exist / discover the correct one to reference. btw thanks so much xy-kong, I used this technique in the guide  https://gist.github.com/neoakris/edc0642a088be2cdc4f5ffe8d90ef5ca#step-33-prepwork-that-will-help-us-determine-what-a-yaml-patch-file-should-look-like

Comment: To clarify some of the above comments, note that this assumes that your current working directory is your chart's root directory. If your chart is in a subdirectory, you can replace the `.` with the location of your chart folder.

Comment: Since the name of the release is irrelevant, suffice to add the -g flag after the "." to generate a random and throwaway name for the release.