# How to install specific yaml files in the helm templates?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

When runing `helm install`

It will automatlly install all the yaml files in the templates folder.If I want to just install several ones I picked for test, what is the best way I can do ?

I have found 2 solutions, adding statements for every file or changing name of files by adding "_".

Is there any easier way by only modifications from the file I pick and command line?

Comment: Make the files themselves conditional via `if` statements in the template and set the relevant values to false.

Comment: it looks like we can do sth like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64810052/deploy-only-one-template-from-the-helm-chart